# The difference between FormCollection.AllKeys and FormCollection.Keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I'm currently poking around inside the `FormCollection` in MVC and wondering about the difference in meaning and expected usage between the `AllKeys` and the `Keys` properties. I know that `AllKeys` is a `string[]` and `Keys` is a `KeysCollection` but if you had to look through the form fields submitted during a post, why would you choose one property over the other? Is it just a convention to use `AllKeys` to quickly check for the existence of a specific key? I have multiple submit buttons on one of my forms and am using `AllKeys` to quickly check which was actually used to submit the form, but it got me thinking about the intended difference between the two, if indeed there is any.

Most of the time I'll be taking advantage of model binding and passing a ViewModel or Command object back to the controller action but are there specific use cases for `FormCollection.Keys` in particular that I'm not aware of? From a quick peek inside `NameValueCollection` and `NameObjectCollectionBase` it looks as though `KeysCollection` is actually simply a collection of strings, rather like a `string[]` in fact. Was one perhaps introduced in a later version of the framework and the other kept as well for backward compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a product of pure inheritance. Take a look at the inheritance diagram chart for FormsCollection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.108).aspx)

**FormsCollection** inherits from **NameValueCollection** which inherits from **NameObjectCollectionBase**. **Keys** are defined in **NameObjectCollectionBase** and inherited by **NameValueCollection** which defines **AllKeys** as a string representstion of all the keys. The sole purpose of NameValueCollection seems to be to expose keys as strings (MSDN: Represents a collection of associated String keys and String values that can be accessed either with the key or with the index)

May be there is more to it, but this is what I found so far for this one. Please post if you (or any one else) finds any other explanations

Comment: Certainly seems like it. I'm guessing that `AllKeys` was added as a convenience. Seems a fairly trivial thing to add when `Keys` does the same job. Thanks for the answer